# Is there a private messaging app without identity?

Tags: chat

I'm looking for an app (mobile or web) that can encrypt messages with a good level (like Signal or Telegram, but on which the users are anonymous.

On signal or telegram, you can be sure of the other's identity because it is ensured by their phone number. I want the users to have personals ID (random numbers or nicknames) that don't have any link with their real identity.

Thus, if I want to communicate with a friend, we just have to exchange our IDs.

Is there such an app?

Comment: Haven't really tried it, but I think Tor chat may be what you're looking for. The project is found here: https://github.com/prof7bit/TorChat/downloads. The builds include windows and linux clients

Comment: That's basically how XMPP/Jabber operates, for example. If you focus on encryption, you probably want the app(s) support OMEMO. Now we miss some details: What OS should the app run on, and what's your price margin? Must there be "counter-parts" available for other OSs?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Wickr](https://www.wickr.com/) can satisfy your criteria. I am not security expert, but [here is link](https://www.wickr.com/security/how-it-works) to description of how they handle their data security for you to evaluate. They have mobile apps that do not require connected phone number. Here is quote directly from description of both iOS and Android apps:

> Anonymous – Your Wickr ID is anonymous to us and anyone outside your Wickr network
>   Your conversations can not be tracked, intercepted or monitored.

A few drawbacks (or features) that you may not like:

1. automatically removes messages after certain period of time, which is not the feature that you asked for. The longest a message can be available for is 6 days.
2. no web interface, only desktop (Windows, Mac, Linux) and mobile (iOS, Android)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, 1 is a bit annoying, but I can understand it. 2 is no problem at all. The biggest problem is that their code is still closed source (although they are changing that). I'm testing https://tox.chat/about.html, https://bitmessage.org/wiki/Main_Page and https://wire.com/en/.

Comment: https://ricochet.im/ seems to be what I'm looking for